# Can i change css property with js to be affected before all the script will be finish to run ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have big script to run.
In the moment it start to run I am execute

```
$("#overlay").fadeIn();
```

but there is big delay until the overlay show (about 3-5 seconds).
any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Javascript is loaded in line with it's position within the HTML document. This means that it will run AFTER any PHP/ASP and if in the footer, after the whole HTML content also. If it's necessary to load it first, put it in the head however this will almost certainly slow doen the loading for the remaining content.

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded. An animation won't run if there is a script keeping the thread busy.